# Export all Eclipse warnings to a file

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, export, report, compiler-warnings

Is there any way I can export all markers Eclipse has found when compiling? A legacy project of mine has quite a bit of warnings and I want to summarize them in a table so I can split them up by e.g. package, type and other factors. If I'm able to build some kind of report file out of them, I would be able to filter them.

I found this [Marker Manager](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/marker-manager) plugin, but there is no documentation anywhere and I don't see how I'm supposed to use it.

Answer (score 1):

I am looking for the same problem.

One solution which I found is to select all warnings in the Problems view by clicking the right mouse button and choose `"Select all"`. Then you could again click the right mouse button, choose `"Copy"` and `"paste"` the warning in an editor.

Maybe this could help you.

I am also looking for a possibility to automatically export the warnings in a file after a build.